# Upper bound on the number of vertex-transitive graphs

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Is there a known upper bound on the number of vertex transitive graphs on $n$ vertices?

Comment: Since vertex transitive graphs are regular, you can get some trivial bounds, but I guess they are not tight. Have you considered this?

Comment: Question was asked on MathOverflow as well, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155349/upper-bound-on-the-number-of-vertex-transitive-graphs).

Comment: The question has an accepted answer at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/a/155446